# Interceptor Authorization header undefined after page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently learning Angular but facing an issue with the interceptor. Whenever I refresh the page, the currently logged-in user becomes undefined, but when I'm first logging in, it works well and only after I refresh it becomes undefined.. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**Authentication Service Class**

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  USER_NAME_SESSION = 'authenticatedUser';
  private url = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string; 

  public login(username: string, password: string): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({Authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username,password)});
    this.http.get<UserLoginDto>(`${this.url}/login`, {headers}).subscribe(response => {
        this.id = response.id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.registerLogin(username,password);
    });
  }
  createBasicAuthToken(username: string, password: string){
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password);
  }

  registerLogin(username, password) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION, username);
    sessionStorage.setItem('userId',this.id.toString());
  }

  logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('userId');
    this.username = null;
    this.password = null;
    this.id = null;
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let loggedInUser = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION);
    if (loggedInUser === null) return false
    return true
  }

  showLoggedInUser(){
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION);
    if(user === null) return '';
    return user;
  }
}
```

**interceptor class**

```
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            const authReq = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': this.authenticationService.createBasicAuthToken(this.authenticationService.username, this.authenticationService.password),
                }),
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

And to get the current logged in user, i am subscribing to the user service and call that method in ngOnInit

```
export class UserComponent {

ngOnInit() {
      this.getUser();
}

user: User = new User();

    getUser() {
      const id = sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
        this.userService.findUserById(+id).subscribe(response => {
          this.user = response;
        });
    }
}
```

After refreshing the page, I get this in the console and the Authorization header in the Network tab becomes undefined. Any way to fix it? [image]

Comment: It seems the problem is that you use `sessionStorage` for storing user data, which live until tab is opened or refreshed. To handle such case, I think you should save data to `localStorage`

Comment: @vitaliykotov i tried swapping sessionStorage with localStorage but i get the same error, didn't quite work

Comment: Another thing is that when you set `Authorization` header in interceptor, you use `username ` and `password ` properties from `authenticationService`. But you set them only on `login`. Try to save `token` to `localStorage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing this seems to have resolved the problem,
changed to this in **authentication service class**

```
  token;
  createBasicAuthToken(username: string, password: string){
    this.token = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password);
    localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
    return this.token;
  }
```

and then in **interceptor class** used the token i have saved

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            const authReq = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token'),
                }),
            });
            return next.handle(authReq);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```